# Did Ubuntu One lose my Firefox bookmarks or don't they get synced?

Tags: ubuntu-one, firefox, bookmarks

I had to reinstall Ubuntu and expected that Ubuntu One would restore my bookmarks like it did the last time, but nothing happens. How can I find out whether they are actually lost or just not synced at the moment?

The [Ubuntu One status page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Status) says:

> **2011-08-26** Syncing of contacts and bookmarks is not working for some
>   users due to server issues. We are currently upgrading hardware and
>   making configuration changes on the client side that should resolve
>   the syncing issues for those impacted.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu One has discontinued bookmark syncing. According to this [announcement](http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/?p=1282):

> Those of you who have already upgraded to 11.10 may have noticed that
>   Ubuntu One no longer supports bookmarks sync, this is because we have
>   decided to discontinue bookmarks sync as a feature. There are a few
>   reasons for this, the main one being that we felt we were not
>   delivering a quality experience to our users. We have been aware for
>   some time about performance issues with bookmark sync and users have
>   feedback that in many cases it’s not been working properly. We would
>   like to apologise to those of you who have been affected by this.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that those haven't been saved at all. The couch service have been rather unstable for some time, but there have been improvements lately.